# Add image on top of another based on CSS class

Tags: html, css, image

I have a bunch of img tags on one of the pages in my site. I want to be able to add a custom image on top of a few of these images based on the css class applied to them

So in case of the statements below

```
<img src="image_path"/>
<img class="newclass" src="image_path"/>
```

I want another image added on top of the 2nd image and nothing on the first image.

Can I do this using CSS?

Thanks.

**Why I want to do it this way**

I can do this using 2 img tags. But it would be easier for me to make changes and add more images by just adding a class name to the img tag rather than adding another img tag itself in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do it in pure CSS with just a single `img` element.

[`:after`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-after) is what you *would* use, but that [doesn't work for `img` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content):

> Note. This specification does not
>   fully define the interaction of
>   :before and :after with replaced
>   elements (such as IMG in HTML). This
>   will be defined in more detail in a
>   future specification.

---

You *could* do it by adding a containing element, and using `:after` on that.

It works "everywhere" http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent - with the exception of IE7.

For whatever reason, this specific usage of `:after` also doesn't work in IE8. It finally works in IE9.

http://jsfiddle.net/AQHnA/

```
<div class="newclass"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" /></div>

.newclass {
    position: relative;
    float: left
}
.newclass img {
    display: block
}
.newclass:after {
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/32x32/f0f/fff);
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0
}
```

Comment: Pretty much, yes. I updated my answer with how you *could* do it, but the lack of IE7/8 support makes it rather useless in my opinion.

Comment: There is no need for `:after`. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: Using 2 img tags now. that seems like the best solution yet!

Answer (score 1):

It's best to have a parent element for your image. This is how you can do it with links (or any other element):

```
.newclass {
    background:url(2.jpg) no-repeat;
    display:inline-block
}
.newclass img {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1
}

<a href="#"><img src="1.jpg" /></a>
<a class="newclass" href="#"><img src="1.jpg" /></a>
```

This works fine in IE5.5, IE6, IE7, IE8 and Safari 5 (browsers that I tested).

**Edit:** thirtydot noticed that this doesn't work if you have a parent container with a background color (because of the `z-index` on the images). See comments.

Comment: It's a nice idea, but `z-index: -1` will come back and screw you, hard: http://jsfiddle.net/WjZxZ/

Comment: It seems that I can't find anyting to fix that. It works on pages without a container though...

Comment: You could fix it with this: http://jsfiddle.net/pMBD8/ - but it's really not a good idea: http://jsfiddle.net/pMBD8/1/ :o

Comment: That might be a solution but it doesn't work on IE7 and below.

Comment: Using `z-index: -1` in Safari 5+ on any element that shares the DOM with a displayed `<object>` (aka Flash), will cause **extremely** [unpredictable visual glitches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745304/safari-jquery-thickbox-massive-visual-glitches).