# z-index is not working as expected

Tags: html, css, z-index

z-index doesnt seem to work :(
I am not sure what I am doing wrong...
please help

**HTML**

```
    <div class="login">
        <div id="container">
           <!-- Hello header -->
           <div id="header">
               <h1 id="site-name">
               <img src="head.jpg" alt="header" />
                    Welcome to <br/>Blah blah</h1>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </div>

            <!-- end header -->


             <!--Hello Content -->
            <div id="content">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br /><br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnlogin_Click" Width="47px"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Login Box */
.login
{
    background: #b6b7bc;
}

#container
{
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid #818181;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#header
{
    text-align:center;
}

img
{   
    z-index: -1;
}
```

currently when setting in img{} position to relative and z-index to 1
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkIjk.png
want to
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6HU8.png

Comment: need more info than "does not work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments, the answer turned out to be:

- Wrap just the text inside `<h1 id="site-name">` in a `span`.
- Use:

  ```
  #site-name {
      position: relative
  }
  #site-name span {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%
  }
  ```

---

For `z-index` to do anything, you need to also add `position: relative`.

However, setting a negative `z-index` value [sometimes does strange things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250757/add-image-on-top-of-another-based-on-css-class/6251089#6251089).

What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: It then makes the image go back behind the container box... so the image isnt visible.

Comment: `"What are you actually trying to do?"`

Comment: trying to have an image behind the header but over the login

Comment: @Angela Kravceviich: Instead of setting `z-index: -1` on the image, set `#header { position: relative; z-index: 1}`.

Comment: I added images to the question where it demonstrates what it makes it look like when that change is made

Comment: @Angela Kravceviich: See http://jsfiddle.net/qgswE/ - note that I wrapped the text inside the `h1` in a `span`.

Comment: Thank you soo much it worked! I was starting to try making a big z-index map for every box :)

Answer (score 1):

add

`position: relative;`

to your `img {}`

Comment: It then makes the image go back behind the container box... so the image isnt visible.

Comment: Well you are making `z-index` a negative value. For it to go behind something should be expected. Make it a non-negative value above 1 to bring it forward.

Comment: when set it to 1 the header then goes under the image. Still dont overlap

Comment: That's what z-index does - it puts things either above or below other elements. What do you mean by 'overlap'?

Comment: It might be worth your while putting an illustration of what you want to achieve in your question...

Comment: Currently http://i.stack.imgur.com/XkIjk.png But i want to  http://i.stack.imgur.com/d6HU8.png

Answer (score 1):

[`z-index`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/z-index) only applies to elements that are `absolute`, `fixed` or `relative`.

The default is `static`, so you'll need to add `position: relative` to your `img`.

Comment: It then makes the image go back behind the container box... so the image isnt visible.

Comment: @Angela Kravceviich: What are you trying to do? `-1` will move the element down the stack.

Comment: trying to have an image behind the header but over the login.

Comment: If you set `position:relative` on the elements you want to re-order, you can then use `z-index` to set them as you wish.  `position:relative` won't be any different to the default unless you explicitly set position values for eg: `top` and `left`, so you should be able to achieve whatever it is that you want.

Comment: well, when i set the position to relative and z-index to 1 then it looks like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/XkIjk.png what I want to achieve is this http://i.stack.imgur.com/d6HU8.png

Comment: Sorry, I can't view those images from behind the firewall.  Basically, if you want to use `z-index` in the way I think you do, you'll need to apply it to more than one of your elements.