# Safari + jQuery thickbox = massive visual glitches?

Tags: css, flash, macos, safari, z-index

I need help determining what the cause of a serious visual glitch is with one of my production websites. It is only happening with Safari - Chrome and all other browsers are fine.

http://www.philanthropicdirectory.org/search

This is a Drupal 6.x website, running the following simultaneously:

- jQuery 1.3.2 (Drupal base/default)
- jQuery 1.4.4 (This is used here and there by overriding the jQuery namespace to '$js' for certain advanced operations 1.3.2 can't handle)
- jQuery UI 1.7.3
- Thickbox 1.8.2.19 (I've slightly modified this .js)

**TO REPRODUCE:**

1. Click link (visit the page): http://www.philanthropicdirectory.org/search
2. Click twice (once to center) on any of the 5 'coverflow' panels to trigger Thickbox content
3. Once TB content loads, resize the browser window horizontally left or right
4. Notice the odd background-image and background-color offsetting
5. Switch between any of the 5 'tab' icons in the upper right of the modal system
6. At any point, use Web Inspector to uncheck and then recheck *any CSS property, anywhere*
7. Notice how this instantly clears/fixes all visual glitches
8. Resize the browser window again or tab between the other tabs, and notice the glitches return.

If you notice the same things I am, it'd be great to get your machine config and Safari version.

- Before
  [image: Before resizing or tabbing]
- After resizing
  [image: After resizing browser slightly]
- After tabbing
  [image: After resizing, then tabbing to another tab]

The images say it all, and as far as I could test, I can only reproduce this problem in the following setup, with Safari:

- MacPro, 6-core Xeon (2010)
- OS X 10.6.8
- 2 monitors: 1x 23" Cinema Display (old silver one) + 1x 27" Apple Cinema Display
- ATI Radeon HD 5770 (Mac version w/01.00.436 Driver)
- Safari 5.1+

I've tested other machines and other machines with earlier versions of Safari (4.x), and the problems are simply not present.

Is there anything you think I can test to figure out why this is happening?

PS: Only using one monitor at a time produces the same problems.

Comment: I've just installed Safari 5.0.3 separately on my MacPro and the same problems are present. This leads me to further believe that it is a graphic card issue or some other software bug.

Comment: Went home and checked my 10.6.8 Macbook Pro with Safari 5.1 (6534.50) - same issues, different video card and hardware. That means it's definitely not the hardware. Perhaps a 10.6.x issue...

Comment: While people take a look at this, what other forum or support site would you recommend I post this problem on? Safari Bugs? Apple? WebKit?

Comment: Safari 5.1 is filled with visual problems. I’m having all sorts of rendering issues on my MBP. Mostly happens when hiding/showing elements – the screen just never refreshes some locations etc. And I’m running Lion, so it’s definitely a Safari issue.

Comment: *Would anyone recommend changing the title to "Safari: negative z-index + Flash = massive visual glitches," since that is exactly what is at play here, and not jQuery? Not sure of the protocol for updating original content based on solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION!**

I noticed this happening with another website we've built - a website with nothing in common with the Drupal one with the problem here, save for the fact that this new one also has a Flash (SWF) file in the `body`, and I was applying a CSS property to an element with a negative `z-index` value.

It was happening on this new website because the container for the `object` in the HTML was set to

```
z-index: -1;
```

in order for elements positioned to overlap the `object` could be clicked on (otherwise, links on top of the `object` could not be interacted with).

I was able to *permanently* fix it by instead setting any elements positioned *on top* of the `object`

```
z-index: 1; /* or anything > 0 */
```

Given that solution, I hunted down any and all "z-index: -1" CSS on the Drupal website and sure enough there was an element within the Thickbox container that was shown on every tab - the big green "SEARCH" input button. It was styled that way because of visual needs (something to do with the fake inner-drop-shadow on the button).

[image: z-index: -1; culprit found!]

I disabled the entire `z-index` property for this element, and lo-and-behold, the funkiness *permanently* disappeared on the Drupal website.

Hurray! It was surely providence that I came across the same issue more acutely on a different website.

Now I'm not sure the exact bug in Safari that is behind this without intense testing, but all I do know is that an `object` on the page + any element near it set to `z-index: -1` equals total meltdown (on a Mac running Safari 5.x).

Comment: Note that there was *absolutely no Javascript* running on the new website where I hit upon the solution. Therefore I'm removing those tags from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I checked in Safari 5.1 (7534.50) on an HP Xeon running Windows 7.  I don't see any glitches.

That's weird.  Sounds like a race condition of some sort.  Maybe there is a bug in your ATI driver?  Since it fixes itself when you re-render it, perhaps you could introduce some delay somewhere which might give it more time to render properly?

Comment: Thanks - I'll keep this open while I continue inspecting. What concerns me is that only Safari has this issue. Chrome is based on the same rendering engine and does not have the problem, which leads me to believe it is a system configuration or software bug. Plus, whenever I touch the Inspector in Safari, things instantly snap back into properly displaying, regardless of what I'm putting in.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I just ran Safari 5.1.1 (7534.51.22) on my Windows 7 Parallels Virtual Machine and there weren't any glitches either.